# Getting "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct node' "error

Tags: c

I'm making a push/pop program using stacks and linked lists. Running into two errors in function pushpancake(). One is "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct node'" and the other says my "top" is undeclared. Some help would be greatly appreciated!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
int main ()
{
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
    };
struct node* top=NULL;

int choice = 0;
printMenu ();


do
{


    printf ("\nEnter a choice. ");  
    scanf ("%d", &choice);


    switch (choice)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            exitProgram();
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            clrScreen();
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            pushpancake();
            break;
        }
         default:
        printf("\nInvalid Choice!\n");
    }
}
    while (choice != 0); 
    return 0;
}


void printMenu ()
{
    printf ("0) Exit program.\n\n");
    printf ("1) Clear Screen.\n\n");
    printf ("2) Display the pancake stack.\n\n");
    printf ("3) Push a pancake.\n\n");
    printf ("4) Pop a pancake.\n\n");

}

void pushpancake()
{
    char pancake[30];
    int calories;
    printf("Enter pancake name and its calories:");
    scanf("%s %d,", pancake, &calories);
    printf("The pancake has been added at the top of the stack.");

    struct node *temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(temp->pancake,pancake);
    temp->data=calories;
    temp->next=top;
    top=temp;
}
```

Comment: I got it actually. My struct node needed to go before my main. My strcpy(temp->pancake,pancake); isnt working though. That's the part i was worried about

Comment: what is `temp->pancake`. `pancake` is not defined in struct node. Neither is `top` defined in function `pushpancake`

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer, hope it is useful for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OK 1
#define ERROR 0

// infinite stack struct
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
    char name[100];
}StackNode,*LinkStackPtr;
typedef struct
{
        LinkStackPtr top;
        int count;
}LinkStack;


void printMenu ();
void clrScreen(); 
void pushpancake(LinkStack *S);
int popancake(LinkStack *S);   
int PrintStackTop(LinkStack S);
int StackLength(LinkStack S);
int ClearStack(LinkStack *S);

// get length of stack
int StackLength(LinkStack S)
{ 
        return S.count;
}

// judge stack if or not empty
int StackEmpty(LinkStack S)
{ 
        if (S.count==0)
                return OK;
        else
                return ERROR;
}

int look(char *strP,int c)
{
        printf("%s ",strP);
        printf("%d     ",c);
        return OK;
}

// print stack 
int PrintStackTop(LinkStack S)
{
        LinkStackPtr p;
        p=S.top;
        if(S.count == 0){
            printf("stack is empty, can't print\n");
            return ERROR;
        }
        else{
            printf("The count of stack value is: %d\n",StackLength(S));
            printf("\nThe value of stack is:\n");
            while(p && S.count){
                look(p->name,p->data);
                p=p->next;
                S.count--;
            }
            printf("\n");
            return OK;
        }
}

// pop a number from stack
int popancake(LinkStack *S)   
{
    LinkStackPtr p;
    if(StackEmpty(*S))
        return ERROR;
    p = S->top;
    S->top = S->top->next;
    free(p);
    S->count--;
    return OK;
}

//push a number to stack
void pushpancake(LinkStack *S)
{
    char pancake[100];
    int calories;
    printf("Enter pancake name and its calories : (format : apple 10) ");
    scanf("%s %d,", pancake, &calories);

    struct node *temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(temp->name,pancake);
    temp->data=calories;

    temp->next=S->top;
    S->top=temp;
    S->count++;

    printf("The pancake has been added at the top of the stack.");
}

// init stack
int InitStack(LinkStack *S)
{ 
        S->top = (LinkStackPtr)malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
        if(!S->top)
                return ERROR;
        S->top=NULL;
        S->count=0;
        return OK;
}

void clrScreen()
{
    system("clear");   // may be error at windows, if yes, commment it.
}

void printMenu ()
{
    printf ("0) Exit program.\n\n");
    printf ("1) Clear Screen.\n\n");
    printf ("2) Display the pancake stack.\n\n");
    printf ("3) Push a pancake.\n\n");
    printf ("4) Pop a pancake.\n\n");

}
int ClearStack(LinkStack *S)
{ 
        LinkStackPtr p,q;
        p=S->top;
        while(p)
        {  
                q=p;
                p=p->next;
                free(q);
        } 
        S->count=0;
        return OK;
}



int main ()
{

    LinkStack s;
    int choice = 0;
    int booL;
    printMenu ();
    InitStack(&s);  

    do
    {


        printf ("\nEnter a choice. (0-4) ");
        scanf ("%d", &choice);


        switch (choice)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                booL = ClearStack(&s);
                if(booL == OK){
                    printf("stack have been clear!\n");
                }
                PrintStackTop(s);
                printf("exit the program! bye bye\n");
                exit(0);   // exit the program
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                clrScreen();
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                PrintStackTop(s);
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                pushpancake(&s);
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                booL = popancake(&s);
                if(booL)
                    printf("delete top of stack by successful!");
                else
                    printf("delete top of stack by failed!");
                break;
            }
            default:
                printf("\nInvalid Choice!\n");
                break;
        }
    }
        while (choice != 0);   // if choice is 0, then exit the program
        return 0;
}
```

this is output :

```
0) Exit program.

1) Clear Screen.

2) Display the pancake stack.

3) Push a pancake.

4) Pop a pancake.


Enter a choice. (0-4) 2
stack is empty, can't print

Enter a choice. (0-4) 3
Enter pancake name and its calories : (format : apple 10) aa 1
The pancake has been added at the top of the stack.
Enter a choice. (0-4) 2
The count of stack value is: 1

The value of stack is:
aa 1     

Enter a choice. (0-4) 3
Enter pancake name and its calories : (format : apple 10) bb 2
The pancake has been added at the top of the stack.
Enter a choice. (0-4) 2
The count of stack value is: 2

The value of stack is:
bb 2     aa 1     

Enter a choice. (0-4) 3
Enter pancake name and its calories : (format : apple 10) cc 3
The pancake has been added at the top of the stack.
Enter a choice. (0-4) 2
The count of stack value is: 3

The value of stack is:
cc 3     bb 2     aa 1     

Enter a choice. (0-4) 4
delete top of stack by successful!
Enter a choice. (0-4) 2
The count of stack value is: 2

The value of stack is:
bb 2     aa 1     

Enter a choice. (0-4) 0
stack have been clear!
stack is empty, can't print
exit the program! bye bye
```

Comment: Try being more specific on how your answer solves the problem rather than posting your whole code without any comments.

Comment: @Sanip Ok.I will add some comments.

Comment: @Adrian Guerra, have a try to run my code. Can it solve your problem? If yes,please accept it.

Comment: Never post code containing line numbers. That's simply not helpful.

Comment: @Lundin, Sorry, I change it.